# Postgres `date` type: SELECTed value is 1 day earlier than INSERTed value

Tags: postgresql, date, sqldatatypes, datagrip

As part of testing another system, I wanted to understand some edge cases around datatypes in Postgres. I ran into this situation that I don't understand.

### The Y10K Bug

I attempt to insert the "maximum" `date` representable in that column type, as per [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-TABLE). For those dates with a CE 5-digit year and up, the date that I get from my select statement is always one *day* earlier than the literal I inserted.

#### Reproduction Steps

```sql
create  table debug.tst_date ( d date);
insert into debug.tst_date values ('5874897-12-31'); -- not ok,
insert into debug.tst_date values ('587489-12-31'); -- not ok
insert into debug.tst_date values ('58748-12-31'); -- not ok
insert into debug.tst_date values ('10000-12-31'); -- not ok
insert into debug.tst_date values ('10000-01-01'); -- not ok
insert into debug.tst_date values ('9999-12-31'); -- ok
insert into debug.tst_date values ('5874-12-31'); -- ok
insert into debug.tst_date values ('2020-12-31'); -- ok

select * from debug.tst_date;
```

#### Output

| d |
| --- |
| 5874897-12-30 |
| 587489-12-30 |
| 58748-12-30 |
| 10000-12-30 |
| 9999-12-31 |
| 9999-12-31 |
| 5874-12-31 |
| 2020-12-31 |

### Discussion

From those same docs, I picked the preferred ISO 8601 date format (YYYY-MM-DD), but of course, for dates as far in the future as I am working with, the standard doesn't quite apply... The breakdown in behavior happens at precisely `1000-01-01`, as you can see with the duplicated value in the results.

Using other literal formats did not improve the behavior, e.g the record created with `insert into debug.tst_date values ('10000.001');` incorrectly gives `9999-12-31`.

So what part of this am I misunderstanding and/or abusing?

#### More Info

It's looking like this is a Jetbrains DataGrip issue than a Postgres one, as that is the client application I've been using to run all the queries above.
In DataGrip, just casting the date literal still shows this same issue: `select '10000-01-01'::date; --> 9999-12-31`.
Interestingly, this does show the right date... `select '10000-01-01'::date::timestamp`

Comment: Works here: `select '5874897-12-31'::date; 12/31/5874897`. `show datestyle; ISO, MDY`. `select '5874897-12-31'::date; 5874897-12-31`. More information is needed 1) Postgres version? 2) How are you generating output? 3) What is `Timezone` set to on your machine?

Comment: Also what is `DateStyle` set to?

Comment: it's looking like this has more to do with the client than the server. will follow up and see if this is replicable outside of DataGrip. DataGrip is looking more like the culprit than postgres (version 11)

Answer (score 1):

It's a DataGrip bug:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-16037

Feel free to watch it in order to be notified once it has updates. See [this article](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241135) if you are not familiar with YouTrack.

Comment: I sure wish I could accept this as an answer, but since it was I who created that bug ticket, this isn't exactly adding to my understanding